# Error in vs_communitycore installing Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise on Windows 10, but always it reports "Visual Studio Core Features > Fatal error during installation".

In the log, I see:

> e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.  e000: Error
>   0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.  e000: Error 0x80070643:
>   Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.  i000: MUX:  Installation
>   size in bytes for package: vs_communitycore MaxAppDrive: 0 
>   MaxSysDrive: 478848699  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 80168635  i000: MUX: 
>   Return Code:0x80070643 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:InstallFiles
>   Restart:None  i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147023293
>   (0x80070643), Error Message=, Result Detail=InstallFiles, Vital=True,
>   Package Action=Install, Package Id=vs_communitycore i000: Setting
>   string variable 'BundleResult' to value '1603' i319: Applied execute
>   package: vs_communitycore, result: 0x80070643, restart: None

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the lack of connection to Internet.

The machine where I want to install Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, was an intranet machine without access to internet.

After configuring a proxy to get access to internet, I installed Visual Studio and finishes Ok.